# Error in R code : unused arguments

Tags: r

I am new to R-script,I have a task to get the summary of all publications that are in google scholar.

Attached is the code snippet:

```
library(scholar)
ids <- c("rrlucpQAAAAJ", "6Cak1YIAAAAJ")
compare_scholars(ids, pagesize = 100)
a <- get_publications(ids, cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE)
```

The execution is giving the error

```
compare_scholars(ids, pagesize = 100)
Error in compare_scholars(ids, pagesize = 100) : 
unused argument(s) (pagesize = 100)
>   a <- get_publications(ids, cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE)
Error in get_publications(ids, cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE) : 
unused argument(s) (cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Try with `compare_scholars(ids)`

Comment: Have you accepted the first question after installing `scholar` and its dependecy `R.cache`? The code wordsk, you just have to use inly one ID in `get_publications(ids[1], cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE)`.

Comment: @ Hackerman hey i accepted all the dependencies and tried as u suggested. output i got is `compare_scholars(ids) Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 a <- get_publications(ids[1], cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000 , flush = FALSE)Error in get_publications(ids[1], cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE) :unused argument(s) (cstart = 0, pagesize = 1000, flush = FALSE)`